# Keeping two separate javascript files / snippets in same namespace

Tags: javascript

I have two files that I load to the browser.

One is loaded directly as embedded script in the initial call.

The other is loaded dynamically by creating a script node and writing to the .innerHTML property.

I have to do things this way.

Both snippets of JavaScript are encapsulated in the module pattern.

Can I give them the same name space like this:

**Pseudo-code**

```
var ns = Module Pattern 1

var ns = Moudule Pattern 2
```

If not, is there another way to give them the same name space so that when they return functions I can access the functions uniformly?

```
ns.function1();
ns.function2();
```

Because this is for one application I'd prefer to have only one namespace.  But as I mentioned I have to load two snippets.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any reasonable mixin implementation, you might try something like:

```
var ns = ns || {};
mixin(ns, Module Pattern 1);

var ns = ns || {};
mixin(ns, Module Pattern 2);
```

Then these can be loaded in any order.

---

Alternately, change your module pattern a little to accept the namespace object as a parameter and supply the same one to both:

```
var ns = ns || {};
(function(namespace) {
    // ...
    namespace.function1 = //...
}(ns));   

// (again for module 2)
```

Comment: Just [search for it](http://google.com/?q=javascript+mixin).  But the basic idea is that it combines the properties of multiple objects into a single one.